# .each is not taking next object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am receiving JSON data from the web. I received the data and create an object in JavaScript.

Here is what I get from the server on success which is stored in the data variable. Now the problem is that I never get the value of `fname` and `lname` every time it shows me the value of first bracket only.

```
[
    { "id": "3", "age": "4"},
    {"fname": "jhon", "lname": "peter"}
]
```

Here is my code

```
success:function(data){
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    //alert(data);
    $(obj).each(function (i,val){
        $.each(val,function(k,v){
            alert("k --> "+k+" v -->"+v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(obj).each(function (i,val){
    $.each(val,function(k,v){
        alert("k --> "+k+" v -->"+v);
    })
})
```

You do miss some brackets there!

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rgJzj/)**

Comment: hi thanks for the reply , I am sorry i missed those . it didnt work with phonegap .

Comment: @user1224233 by "it didnt work with phonegap" you mean what exactly? You're getting errors of any kind? By the way this answer suits your question and it's fully valid. You didn't mention anything about phonegap previously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the length of obj and then loop through using for loop to get each javascript object.

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: for ur logic i get all the data but as object like this
[object Object]

Comment: you can access the elements using `obj[i].` element.

Comment: for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
for( x in obj[i])
{
 alert(x);   
}
}
it shows me id , age , fname but not values . I am sorry i am new to it what should i use so it show me the values too

Comment: can u upload the snapshot with object in console

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success:function(data){
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  //alert(data);
  $(obj).each(function (i,val){
    for (var v in val) {
      if (val.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
         alert("k --> "+v+" v -->"+val[v]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will print out the key=>value pairs in the object whilst missing out the standard Javascript object properties.